# How to construct Manager object in http-conduit?

Tags: haskell

Continuing my quest to perform a [dropbox query](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#request-token) I am using [http-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/http-conduit/1.1.0.1/doc/html/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html) to try and perform a POST request, but I am not sure how to construct the `Manager` object.

Here is what I got so far (and the problematic line):

```
data DropboxConfig = DropboxConfig { appKey :: String, appSecret :: String}

main = do
    let appKey = "asdfasdfasdfs"
    let appSecret = ";lkj;lkjlkjlkj"
    let config = DropboxConfig {appKey = appKey, appSecret = appSecret}
    let qs = buildQueryString config

    let req = def {method = methodPost, queryString = qs}

    resp <- http req (newManager)  --!Does Not work
    putStrLn $ unpack resp


buildQueryString :: DropboxConfig -> ByteString
buildQueryString config = pack $ "oauth_consumer_key="++(appKey config)++
        "&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1"++
        "&oauth_timestamp=137131200" ++
        "&oauth_nonce=4572616e48616d6d65724c61686176" ++
        "&oauth_signature=wOJIO9A2W5mFwDgiDvZbTSMK%2FPY%3D
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
    Couldn't match expected type `http-conduit-1.3.0.1:Network.HTTP.Conduit.Manager.Manager'
                with actual type `http-conduit-1.3.0.1:Network.HTTP.Conduit.Manager.ManagerSettings
                                  -> IO http-conduit-1.3.0.1:Network.HTTP.Conduit.Manager.Manager'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type signature says it all, really:

```
newManager :: ManagerSettings -> IO Manager
```

This is an IO action, so you'll have to bind it using `<-` as always. It also requires `ManagerSettings`, so you'll need to provide that. Something like this should do it, I think (not too familiar with the library, just following the types):

```
manager <- newManager def
resp <- http req manager
```

Though, it might be a better idea to use `withManager` so you don't have to worry about closing it yourself.

```
withManager $ \manager -> do
  resp <- http req manager
  ...
```

Comment: Where did you get that `newManager` method? I see this one `newManager :: ResourceIO m => ResourceT m Manager` here: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/http-conduit/1.1.0.1/doc/html/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#t:Manager

Comment: @drozzy: Change the `1.1.0.1` part of the URL to `latest`. Google has a bad tendency of linking you to old versions of API docs on Hackage.

Comment: Alternatively use local documentation... That way you always have the correct documentation for the version you are using (which might not necessarily be the latest)

Comment: Just out of interest, how would you do it with the old way of 1.1.0.1?

Comment: @drozzy: There's an example at the top of the page you linked.